# Did two brothers steal credit card information worth millions and walked away scot-free because banks were embarrassed?

Tags: economics, security, hacking, lawsuits

In [this DEFCON talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET0MFkRorbo) at around 24:52 minute mark, the speaker (a Cambridge professor) tells a story of two brothers stealing millions of dollars using a weakness in credit card terminal technology, and then walking away scot-free because banks were too embarrassed to show any evidence against them. I was trying to find any other sources for this story before sharing it with my friends, but couldn't find anything. Is this story true?

Comment: I think it was more than the embarrassment stated. That wasn't the only vulnerability, and the professor later says (26:00) that the banks were keen to blame users for (allegedly) making their PIN known, and at 32:05 the point about the unwillingness of banks to admit to the vulnerability is repeated. After all, if they admit there is a problem, that could mean accepting liability.